# C# DataGridviewComboBoxColumn doesnt do anything when clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am very confused with what is happening here. I have a `DataGridviewComboBoxColumn` that I want to act like a combobox (clearly). I have the following code:

Code in designer.cs:

```
this.PurposeCol.DataPropertyName = "Purpose";
this.PurposeCol.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
this.PurposeCol.HeaderText = "Purpose";
this.PurposeCol.Name = "PurposeCol";
this.PurposeCol.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.PurposeCol.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
this.PurposeCol.Width = 78;
```

Constructor on form page:

```
PurposeCol.ReadOnly = false;
PurposeCol.DataSource = tripPurposeComboBox.Items;  //Verified that this line fills the datasource with 14 items          
PurposeCol.DisplayMember = "ItemText";
PurposeCol.ValueMember = "ItemValue";
```

The problem is that when I click it nothing happens. The text displayed is what I am expecting, and I can confirm that there are 14 items in the `DataSource`, but I cannot seem to get any other items to display. Is there a special setting that needs to be set before `DataGridviewComboBoxColumn` to act like a `ComboBox`?

Comment: Did you try double click on the cell? Is it opens but you have no items at all?

Comment: The dropdown arrow is highlighted, and a single value is displayed, but nothing happens when I click or double click it. I have a click event handler for that `datagridview` as well, and that does not get fired. 

It does have items, but does not open.

Comment: I think I had a similar issue before, make sure you don't have other related events that may interrupt, and also make sure the cell is not marked as read only (when I say make sure, use debugger to check at run-time)

Comment: There are a lot of event handlers on this datagridview which could be causing issues. Maybe I can just write code to force the combobox to open instead?

Comment: It ended up being a dependency to another class (`DataPropertyName`) which did not have a set property, and only a get. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

You set the `ReadOnly` property to `False` for the column, but make sure the `DataGridView.ReadOnly` property is set to `False` too *(it normally is by default)*.

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
```

If it's set to `True`, it will override the `ReadOnly` property on your column, and you won't be able to open the drop-down.

Comment: Both of those items are set to false, but that did not resolve the issue. There are a ton of event handlers on this code which could be causing issues though. I will have to keep digging

Answer (score 0):

To use it as editable combobox, you need to implement validating event for combobox cell while editing control showing
eg.

```
 private void datagrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (datagrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl cbo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
                cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

                cbo.Validating += new CancelEventHandler(cbo_Validating);
                cbo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(SpacingComBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }

        }
    }
```

and implement cbo_Validating and SpacingComBox_SelectedIndexChanged

> void cbo_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) private void
>   SpacingComBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)